# Can we install both version Mule AnyPoint Studio July 2014 and June 2015 Release in same PC without any conflicts?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I have a small query generally. I'm working on the studio July 2015 release with 3.5.1 runTime for my client Project. However I'm willing to install AnyPoint June 2015  with runtime 3.7 release for my POC purpose. Does it conflict each by any chance (or override while installing). I don't want to override or update July 2015( It should not be disturbed in any ways) with new since my project running on it.

If I want to install the June 2015 what all the step need to take care? or don't require any? . Please advice.

Comment: Do you know that it's possible to install different runtimes? You should be able to install runtime 3.5.1 in AnyPoint June 2015.

Comment: @DavidDossot Thanks for the response. Yes, June 2015, we can  update different Runtime ( Update site url) and deploy whatever runtime which we required.  Can we install Anypoint Studio June 2015?? in the same PC which we have installed july 2014. All I want is I need to do POC on dataweaver and other components in latest release.At the same time it shouldn't collapse with July2014 version( Since My project is developed on this version, may get requirement anytime)

Comment: Which means two eclipse( Anypoint Studio) need to open one for my POC( July 2015  and other for  Project( June 2014 release).Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem installing several versions of Anypoint Studio as there is no problem in installing several versions of Eclipse on the same machine. Just install the different versions in different directories.

You should also be able to use the same workspace across versions, with potential weird effects if incompatible features are used in projects opened with the two versions (which is not what you'll do, so you should be fine).

Comment: Thank you for the response!